# Convert String (MMM, dd, YYYY hh:mm AM/PM) to datetime - three letter month

Tags: apex

How can we convert "Dec 5, 2018 3:14 PM" (with three letter month) to datetime format. Tried both Parse and ValueOf and they did not work.

```
DateTime.Parse('Dec 5, 2018 3:14 PM');
DateTime.ValueOf('Dec 5, 2018 3:14 PM');
```

We have this date in a json file that we need to process.

Even this did not work

```
system.debug(Json.deserialize('Dec 5, 2018 3:14 PM', DateTime.Class));
```

Comment: You have to manually parse string and manually create an instance of DateTime using `Datetime newInstance(Integer year, Integer month, Integer day, Integer hour, Integer minute, Integer second)`

Comment: @glls This is of different format and those solutions will not work for this case

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing. Let me know if there is better way to achieve this

```
string dt = 'Dec 5, 2018 3:14 PM';
        Map<String, Integer> monthMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        monthMap.put('Jan',1);
        monthMap.put('Feb',2);
        monthMap.put('Mar',3);
        monthMap.put('Apr',4);
        monthMap.put('May',5);
        monthMap.put('Jun',6);
        monthMap.put('Jul',7);
        monthMap.put('Aug',8);
        monthMap.put('Sep',9);
        monthMap.put('Oct',10);
        monthMap.put('Nov',11);
        monthMap.put('Dec',12);

        string[] strList = dt.split(' ');
        Integer month = monthMap.get(strList[0]);
        Integer day = Integer.valueOf(strList[1].replace(',',''));
        Integer year = Integer.valueOf(strList[2]);
       string newdt = month+'/'+ day+'/'+year + ' ' + strList[3] + ' ' + strList[4];
        DateTime expected = DateTime.parse(newdt);
```

Comment: Sounds perfect to me. Just an addittion, if its PM you have to add +12 to your hours

Comment: DateTime.Parse('12/5/2018 3:14 PM') should work without +12 right ?

Comment: You can save ~12 lines of code by making a List and then using indexOf to find the month's index. `String[] monthList = ',Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(',');` ... `Integer month = monthList.indexOf(strList[0]);`

Comment: @sfdcfox good one